# Enviar html por medio de emails

Tags: php, base-de-datos, wordpress, email

Buenas tengo una web y he creado un apartado donde si los usuarios ponen un identificador (numero de una tarjeta) se le envía un email a su correo donde se les muestra un enlace que tiene unos parámetros en la url y les redirecciona a otra pagina, hasta hay sin problema, lo complicado viene cuando quiero que en el correo se vea html, y que el enlace este en un botón, el cual lo redireccione a la pagina con los parámetros todavía en la url, he visto distintos métodos para hacerlo pero no me funcionan.

https://andres-dev.com/enviar-correos-usando-wp-mail-wordpress/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

supongo que sera error mio pero no doy con el

Ahora mismo tengo este codigo que funciona perfectamente:

```
    $NumTarjetaFidelizacion3 = $_POST['numTarjeta'];

if (!empty($NumTarjetaFidelizacion3) && isset($_POST['recuperar'])){

global $wpdb;
$datos = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta=$NumTarjetaFidelizacion3"));

$ClaveTarjeta2=$datos[0]->Clavetarjeta;

wp_mail($datos[0]->email, "Recuperar contraseña NikkiClub", "
    Se ha solicitado el restablecimiento de su contraseña en NikkiClub.
    Si usted no ha solicitado restablecer su contraseña ignore este correo.

    Para restablecer su contraseña haga click en el siguiente enlace:
    https://www.nikkiclub.es/confirmar-contrasena/?numtarjeta=$NumTarjetaFidelizacion3&clavetarjeta=$ClaveTarjeta2");

}
```

Pero al implementar lo que hay en las webs no me funciona, si pudierais pasarme un codigo de muestra en el que funcione lo agradeceria

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos problemas en tu código:

1. El contenido no está construido usando las etiquetas HTML adecuadas
2. Debes indicar a `wp_mail` que el tipo de contenido es HTML, porque por defecto el contenido es `text/plain`.

Si lo haces así debería funcionar:

```
<?php 
    $to = !empty($datos[0]->email) ? $datos[0]->email : NULL;
    if ($to){
        $subject = "Recuperar contraseña NikkiClub";
        $body = "<p>Se ha solicitado el restablecimiento de su contraseña en NikkiClub.</p>
                 <p>Si usted no ha solicitado restablecer su contraseña ignore este correo.</p>
                 <p>Para restablecer su contraseña haga click en el siguiente enlace: <br>
                    <a href=\"https://www.nikkiclub.es/confirmar-contrasena/?numtarjeta=$NumTarjetaFidelizacion3&clavetarjeta=$ClaveTarjeta2\">restablecer</a>";
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers ) ){
            $txtOutput="Mensaje enviado correctamente";
        } else {
            $txtOutput="Error enviando el mensaje"; 
        }   
    } else {
        $txtOutput="No se recibió la dirección de correo electrónico";      
    }
    echo $txtOutput;
?>
```